# Need help identifying Objects in Siebel Web Application for Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have my application which is siebel based and does not support Firefox. I have added all add-ons on Firefox.

Could someone please tell me how to identify the objects in the application as i can later use :
`webdriver driver = new internetexplorerdriver();' 
to run my application.

Since my application does not support Firefox. How do i find the objects using xpath, etc.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
VJ.

Comment: In Internet Explorer, press F12.

Comment: THere is no direct way to identify xpath of an element using IE. As SiKing said, press F12. It fetches the complete HTML of the page. Use "select element by click' to identify the element in your web page. Once you click an element in your webpage, the HTML part of it is displayed in the console. You can then decide on whether to use name, id, class to identify the element. If you still need XPATH, then its the right time to start learning XPATH formation. You can start ffrom here http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hi for IE you can use the 'fire-ie-selenium' which is a macro enabled extension....from the below path

https://code.google.com/p/fire-ie-selenium/downloads/list

Download the latest one i.e. "Fire-IEBrowser1.4".

Again mind you **this may not work in all the cases**, but in your case when you don't have any other option you can make best use of it. Have a try.

Cheers